# Windows Phone 10 Emulator: XDE fails to start ("Provider Load failure")

Tags: windows-phone, emulation, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to build and deploy an application to a freshly installed VS2015 and emulator. The build succeeds, but the deploy fails.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Smarty2, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2459,5): warning : APPX4001: Build property AppxBundlePlatforms is not explicitly set and is calculated based on currently building architecture. Use 'Create App Package' wizard or edit project file to set it.
2>------ Deploy started: Project: ___, Configuration: Debug x86 ------

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device 'DA831653-315E-41D9-BF63-CCCE346F4E9C'.': 
Exception - 0x80131500  ___
```

I tried running the emulator directly using [this answer from `How to run the Windows Phone 10 Emulator?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31497317/6796409) , but it failed with the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Management.ManagementException: Provider load failure 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__94`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Xde.Wmi.NetNat.FindNatObj(String natName)
   at Microsoft.Xde.Wmi.NetNat.IsSupported()
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.XdeController.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Xde.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I checked Hyper-V using the [accepted answer here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/22690b57-b5ba-4551-a9d2-5a4e409c566c/check-whether-hyperv-is-running-stopped-or-not?forum=winserverhyperv) and it said it's available.

I'm at a loss, what can I do to fix this?